# SnapShotListener vs FCM

Tags: firebase

I was wondering the differences between snapshotlisteners and Firebase Cloud Messaging. Both can trigger my code to respond to server side code ( like Cloud Functions ).

If I understand correctly, the snapshotlisteners gets triggered when I write something to the database, and FCM service gets triggered when I send a message from Cloud Functions. What is more efficient in the following use case:

I have a game which the user can play. He sends his move to the database, and a cloud function checks his move. The user is waiting to get a response back from the server, to see if he got it right or wrong. Should I:

> Add a snapshotlistener, write from the cloud function to that document, respond to to the trigger from the listener, and delete the
>   document afterwards

or

> Add the FCM service and send the message from cloud function to the device somehow

I do not know the differences between a notification (FCM) and a listener (snapshotlistener). I do not want any pop-up, like an apple notification, but I just want my code to be notify so I can respond from the output of the cloud function.

Comment: You might want to take a look at each product's documentation to get a sense of how they are intended to be used.  They're not very similar.  One is a realtime database, the other is a push messaging system.

Comment: @DougStevenson yes I know, but both can trigger code as a respons to a cloud function. I am trying to find out what the best proeuct is for the example I provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database listeners are only reliably active if the user is actively using your app. So if the player submits a move, then switches to another app and forgets about the game, they might never see the update from Cloud Functions.

Firebase Cloud Messaging on the other hand can be delivered no matter if the app is active or not. So those are a great way to pull the player back into the game from Cloud Functions.

Which one is best for your use-case likely depends on the time it takes to process the move (or whatever else the function does). If it's a few seconds, you could use a database listener to communicate results. If it's longer, FCM might be better.